# Parameterizing class property

Tags: python

I am doing something with Pygame Rect objects and Rects have a lot of properties I can use to reposition it.

[Pygame Rect Doc](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html). Here, just below the initial links in a yellow box, is a list of potential attributes.

Here is example code that correctly implements what I want to do.

```
def reposition(rect, attr, pos):
    if attr not in {"top", "left", "bottom", "right"}:  # etc
        raise ValueError

    if attr == "top":
        rect.top = pos
    elif attr == "left":
        rect.left = pos
    elif attr == "bottom":
        rect.bottom = pos
    elif attr == "right":
        rect.right = pos
    # etc
        
    return rect
```

This however is clunky and kind of gross so I'd prefer to do something more like the following.

```
def reposition(rect, attr, pos):
    rect.attr = pos
    return rect
```

I know this doesn't work but does there exist a way to do something like this, that is concise and not clunky?

Comment: How about just setting the attributes of rect directly instead of using a superfluous method?

Comment: I am creating a wrapper for an operation I do a lot. This is a simplified example for demo purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setattr()` for this.

Comment: Oh…how exactly?

Comment: If I understand correctly, "setattr(rect, attr, pos)". Not sure why this was downvoted. This appears to do exactly what I want.